# Part of input field does not show if automation is used

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu

My selenium test automates parts of Salesforce. When the page is opened certain fields do not show. When the product name is chosen a couple of extra input fields should show. This works fine manually. When the automation is run the extra fields do not show. Any idea why?
Is there some thing that can be done to trigger so that the extra field (Maximum Device Count) shows? **Is it possible to accomplish with say JavaScriptExecutor or some other way**?

This is before option is NOT selected:
[image]

After Product Name is selected, it shows Maximum Device Count:

[image]

Here is the html code (sorry could not copy it). The circled path is "block" when the extra field shows. If not its "none"

[image]

This is the code (Unable to add as code so added as a pic).
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: After selecting the field, which triggers the other field, click outside (anywhere) so that the first field changes get reflect on the page. If you can share the site link, if possible, will be more helpful because the code you shared is minimal.

Comment: I have tried clicking on another place in the page and did not help. Is there something else that need to be done? Btw, that is all the code I have. Sorry I can not share the site link and it will not work anyway outside the company.